# Application Insights not logging anything in Azure from .Net without using CancellationToken

Tags: .net, azure-application-insights, telemetry

I am getting an issue while using the following code to Log to Application Insights:

```
var configuration = new TelemetryConfiguration();
            configuration.InstrumentationKey = "KEY";
            var client = new TelemetryClient(configuration);
            client.TrackEvent($"TEST EVENT", properties: new Dictionary<string, string>() { { $"TEST Property", $"TEST Value".ToString() } });
```

Whenever I am using the below code, the telemetry gets logged without issue, however, as this is not an Async call, we never get `IsCancellationRequested` as `FALSE` and this goes to infinite loop.

```
CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
            CancellationToken token = tokenSource.Token;
            var configuration = new TelemetryConfiguration();
            configuration.InstrumentationKey = "KEY";
            var client = new TelemetryClient(configuration);
            while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                client.TrackEvent($"TEST EVENT", properties: new Dictionary<string, string>() { { $"TEST Property", $"TEST Value".ToString() } });
            }
```

Can someone please help me to identify if I am missing something here?

-Shalabh

Comment: We might be looking at a potential bug:https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/issues/416

Answer (score 0):

There are couple possible reasons:

- You are creating new `TelemetryConfiguration` object and it defaults to the simple Telemetry Channel that has no retries / no local storage, so network issues will lead to the events being lost. You can use `TelemetryConfiguration.Active` which is initialized from ApplicationInsights.config and will use `ServerTelemetryChannel` with retries and local storage.
- The application may exit immediately after the method is executed giving no chance to fill the telemetry buffer and send the telemetry. You may use `Flush()` if that's the case. `Flush()` alone won't help unless you have implemented [synchronous channel](http://apmtips.com/blog/2016/11/10/sync-channel/), so you may want to add a `Sleep()` as well.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to see if that works. Most of the samples shared here [link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31192.custom-telemetry-events-with-trackevent-in-microsoft-application-insights.aspx) and [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-api-custom-events-metrics#trackevent) does not talk specifically about using a TelemetryChannel.

Is it mandatory to use it? Can't we just call a .TraceEvent directly?

Comment: Yep, you definitely can call TrackEvent() directly. The channel is that's used behind the scenes to deliver it. For long-running apps, almost any channel is fine. For short-lived apps, default channels are not the best.

Comment: Hi @Dmitry Matveev, Thanks for your reply. I tried the same code (with channel) in a console app and it works. However, when trying to write it from a CRM Online Plugin, it fails. CRM Online is OAuth Protected. Do you think there are some challenges writing from it? I referenced https://celedonpartners.com/blog/understanding-your-dynamics-crm-instance-with-application-insights/